# Why am I getting AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x602000000058 error on leetcode?

Tags: c++, buffer-overflow

I have read few other answers and checked a blog on codeforces. All suggest that it must be some potential overflow. I have tested it for all the testcases from n = 1 to n = 45. I don't see that overflow.

```
class Solution {
public:
    int checkSteps(int n, vector<int>&cache){
       if(n <= 0)
         return cache[0];
       else if(n == 1){
           return cache[1];
       }
       else if(n == 2){
           return cache[2];
       }
       if(cache[n] > 0) return cache[n];
       cache[n] = checkSteps(n-1, cache) + checkSteps(n-2, cache);
        return cache[n];
    }

   int climbStairs(int n){
           vector<int> cache(n+1, 0);
           cache[0] = 0;
           cache[1] = 1;
           cache[2] = 2;
          int result = checkSteps(n, cache);
           return result;

   }
```

Comment: `all the testcases from n = 1` Replace `cache[2]` with `cache.at(2)` and test again.

Comment: `return cache[0];` -- What if `cache` is empty?   This is an out-of-bounds access.

Comment: If `n` is 1, then `climbStairs` already starts off wrong, before even calling `checkSteps`.  There is no `cache[2]` if `n == 1`.   If you use `at()` as proposed in the earlier comment, you will now get an `std::out_of_range` exception thrown instead of an "AddressSanitizer" error.

Comment: @dxiv thanks I get it now, it's stupid.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks, I have tested it now and figure the same. About returning return cache[0], Inputs are positive so cache[0] should never be empty.

Comment: this is link to the question https://leetcode.com/problems/climbing-stairs/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Fib Number formula ([Golden Ratio](https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/fibonacci-sequence.html)) for this problem, will get accepted:

```
struct Solution {
    static const inline int climbStairs(const int n) {
        double ways = 1 / pow(5, 0.5) * (pow((1 + pow(5, 0.5)) / 2, -~n) - pow((1 - pow(5, 0.5)) / 2, -~n));
        return (int) ways;
    }
};
```

- `-~n` is simply (`n + 1`), just a bit shorter

or based on your approach, we would just iterate:

```
struct Solution {
    static const inline int climbStairs(const int n) {
        int first = 1;
        int second = 0;
        int ways = 0;

        for (int iter = 0; iter < n; iter++) {
            ways = first + second;
            second = first;
            first = ways;
        }

        return ways;
    }
};
```

---

### References

- For additional details, you can see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/climbing-stairs/discuss/). There are plenty of accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) and explanations, efficient algorithms, as well as asymptotic [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) complexity analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup> in there.

#### If you are preparing for [interviews](https://leetcode.com/problemset/top-interview-questions/?listId=wpwgkgt):

- We would want to write [bug-free](https://www.codegrip.tech/productivity/tips-to-write-bug-free-code-during-interview/) and [clean](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-write-cleaner-code-during-onsite-interviews) codes based on standards and conventions (e.g., [c](/questions/tagged/c)<sup>[1](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/lab/cplus/cstyle.html), [2](https://users.ece.cmu.edu/%7Eeno/coding/CCodingStandard.html)</sup>, [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)<sup>[1](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html), [2](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/coding-standards)</sup>, [java](/questions/tagged/java)<sup>[1](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html), [2](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf)</sup>, [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)<sup>[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions), [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/?redirectedfrom=MSDN)</sup>, [python](/questions/tagged/python)<sup>[1](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)</sup>, [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)<sup>[1](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html)</sup>, [go](/questions/tagged/go)<sup>[1](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments)</sup>, [rust](/questions/tagged/rust)<sup>[1](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0/style/)</sup>).

Comment: yeah, It is easy one, I used dynamic programming when I was stuck on this bug, got accepted. thanks!!